# Nested Resource - How to pass needed keys, and attribute to update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My nested resources are working for form_for updates, but I have a few toggles that I need to setup to change a status field.  So I am using link_to, and accessing the url helper.

```
   link_to "toggle", edit_project_expense_path(@project[:id],expense_item[:id])
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :projects do
    resources :expenses
  end

  match '/submit_expense/:id' => 'expenses#submit_expense', :as => 'submit_expense'
```

rake routes

```
edit_project_expense GET    /projects/:project_id/expenses/:id/edit(.:format) expenses#edit
```

My question is:  How can I also send along :approval_status = "1", with my link_to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  link_to "toggle", edit_project_expense_path(@project[:id],expense_item[:id], approval_status: 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a big help.

Comment: How would I route this to my update method?  I suppose this is why people use custom routes....